# Emailing Processing Bounces

Tags: php, email, email-bounces

I have a database that contains 20K of what the email I was sending newletter The problem I found was that each of the email I sent back type

Delivery Status Notification (Failure)

I am willing to transfer this email which is inactive knowing that I filter all email from the standpoint of the field formatting and existence.

as I have to see how little research has addressed this problem I find the notion that bounces are already implemented on the software.

If any one has any That a idea how I can apply that bounces in the php will be welcome

cordially

Comment: This is really hard to understand. Can I suggest you edit the question by taking out all the bits that aren't needed (like how many emails are in the database) and add in stuff along the lines of exactly what you want help with and how you have tried to do it, or what you think is the right gist, but not sure of the right method - it would make this question much easier to understand.

Comment: What method are you calling to send the email? Show your work. (Treat this like a mathematics exam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's pretty hard to understand what are you talking about, but...

As you mentioned, when e-mail can't be delivered (for many reasons) you will get Delivery Status Notification which will goes to inbox of e-mail that you used to send the message.

For example, if you send newsletter from **newsletter@test.com** to **customer@test.com** and the message can't be delivered then you get notification at **newsletter@test.com**. So just open your **newsletter@test.com** inbox with php, read the messages, parse them, and save the errors (if occurs) in database, matching by e-mail.

This link could be useful:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

If you have your mailbox at your own server then the thing is much simpler, because all you need to do is to make ln, and then just open the file to parse.

```
ln -s /var/mail/my-inbox /var/www/my-script/inbox
```